# open access password protected database only with password

Tags: c#-4.0

This is my connection string for opening an access database which is password protected:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=paya.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=24577854;"
```

I want my application to not work if the database password is removed.

Comment: Do you get a prompt when you try without the password? Omitting the password parameter will make it 'not work' automatically

Comment: yes. the app works even if i remove database password